# Response.ContentType sporaticly changes for IE8 using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, iis

We are running ASP.NET MVC on IIS6.  We have started to notice a problem with IE8 clients.
Almost all the time, the ContentType returned is 'text/html' but occasionally, it will be returned as 'application/xhtml+xml'.  This is causing IE8 to try and download the file instead of rendering the contents in the browsers.

I can't find any reason for the ContentType to change.  The requests from the browser look the same.

1. Where is the ContentType set in the ASP.NET/MVC pipeline?
2. Any ideas what might be causing certain requests to change the ContentType?

**Updated Information**

- We are using the default ViewEngine provided with the MVC framework.
- This is happening on multiple machines.

Comment: How are your views constructed? Are they same view returning different types? What `ActionResult` are you using?

Comment: Does it occur on the same clients or is is distributed across multiple machines?

Comment: I updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somebody is trying to vary the content-type based on the User-Agent request header; sending text/html to IE because it doesn't support XHTML.

If this is the case, maybe there's an intermediate (proxy) serving you a response for a different UA. Check Cache-Control and Vary response headers.

Comment: There's no proxy between the clients and the server.  They are the same network.